# http verb for route helper function

Tags: http, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

I have a restful controller and I want to use the destroy function
this is my route :

```
 +-------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
 |URI                            |Name                   |Action                |
 +-------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
 |GET|HEAD playwright/play/{play}|playwright.play.show   |PlayController@show   |
 +-------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
 |DELETE playwright/play/{play}  |playwright.play.destroy|PlayController@destroy|
 +-------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

I'm using this link

```
<a href="{{action('PlayController@destroy', $play->id)}}">Delete</a>
```

And it is always calling the `show($id)` function. So the it is using the GET verb instead of DELETE. 
Is there a way to specify the http verb in the `route()`helper function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a form to do that.

The form needs to POST to the right URI:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::route('playwright.play.destroy'), 'method' => 'DELETE')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Delete me!')}}              
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Information on Laravel forms can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/html)

Comment: thanks, it works now. you think this is the only way to do it?

Comment: Yes. An <a> tag always makes the browser do a GET request to the page in the href attribute. No way to set a verb.

Comment: Well, forms only support GET and POST. So what happens here is that you tunnel DELETE through POST.

Comment: Classic question. Watch the `note` in the [Form builder documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form). This is the way all frameworks, PHP and non-PHP go around this old browser limitation.

Comment: The point being that you really are *not* using DELETE but POST. What counts is what's on the wire, and that's a POST.

Comment: @JulianReschke You can always throw in JS to perform an AJAX call. But **momo** just wanted a full page redirect. I'm sorry to disappoint you.