# Deletion Form For Laravel App

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am not sure why I'm receiving a NotFoundHTTPException when I click on my delete button in my Laravel application.

index.blade.php

```
<form action="/users/3" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="DELETE" name="_method">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-defaul" data-original-title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" type="submit">
</form>
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Gate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy()
    {
        return 'yes';
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('users', ['as' => 'users', 'uses' => 'UsersController@index']);
Route::get('users/{user}', ['as' => 'users.show', 'uses' => 'UsersController@show']);
Route::get('users/{user}/edit', ['as' => 'users.edit', 'uses' => 'UsersController@edit']);
Route::delete('users/{user}', ['as' => 'users.delete', 'uses' => 'UsersController@destroy']);
```

Comment: you sure it is NotFoundHTTPException ? The code seems to be right but maybe there is an issue with CSRF check?

Comment: or did you try moving the delete route before the second get route?

Comment: Can you show the relevant output from `php artisan route:list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.blade.php

```
<form action="{{url('/users/3')}}" method="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-defaul" data-original-title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" type="submit">
</form>
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Gate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        return 'yes';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the form:

```
<form action="/users/3" method="DELETE">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-defaul" data-original-title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" type="submit">
</form>
```

You are using `POST` and you haven't defined a route for the "DELETE" verb. Either define a post instead of a delete route (Route::post(...)) or change the form to user the delete method as described above.

Comment: I thought with Laravel you have to fake it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063966/http-verb-for-route-helper-function @user3732216

Comment: @user3732216 have you tried this? https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html says delete is available. and also HTML supports method="DELETE" in forms. What's the issue then?

Comment: Laravel uses method spoofing. The form should use the method "POST", and have an input named "_method" with a value of "DELETE". While making HTML forms support the PUT and DELETE methods was briefly part of the HTML5 spec, it no longer is, and it cannot be assumed that browsers that may have supported it at one point will continue to do so.

Comment: @patricus you are right. I just read again the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
<form action="/users/3" method="POST">
```

To the following:

```
<form action="<?= route('users.delete', [$user]) ?>" method="POST">
```

Comment: Chances are `action="/users/3"` won't point to the correct url if he is using something like `xampp` or `wamp`, I have experienced this while using `xampp` previously.